# Create a string for sql statement from function **keywords

Tags: python, sql, sqlite, csv

I have a csv file 'users.csv' that looks like this:

```
AppID,Perm,LastLogon,Email,FirstName
jimmeny1,admin,today,jim5@zerlina.com,pop1
jimmeny2,admin,today,jim10@zerlina.com,pop2
jimmeny3,admin,today,jim6@zerlina.com,pop3
```

I created the below function to load any number of columns from a csv into a sqlite table:

```
import sqlite3, csv

def bulkload(file, **args):
    sqlite = sqlite3.connect('mydb.db')
    s1 = sqlite.cursor()
    cols_string = '('
    cols = []
    for i in args.iteritems():
        col = '{} {}'.format(i[0], i[1][1])
        cols.append(col)
    for x, i in enumerate(cols):
        if x != len(cols) - 1:
            cols_string += i + ','
        if x == len(cols) - 1:
            cols_string += i + ')'
    sql1 = "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS mytable {}".format(cols_string)
    s1.execute(sql1)
```

An example call to the function:

```
bulkload('users.csv', appid=(0, 'text'), perm=(1,'text'), email=(3,'text'))
```

Is there an easier or more elegant or simply more pythonic way to create the string 'cols_string' that declares the column names and storage classes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should replace the following

```
cols_string = '('
for x, i in enumerate(cols):
    if x != len(cols) - 1:
        cols_string += i + ','
    if x == len(cols) - 1:
        cols_string += i + ')'
```

with the following, which is more pythonic & faster too (due to ''.join() method)

```
cols_string = '(' + ','.join(cols) + ')'
```

Comment: This is great, thanks @Ashish. I'm going to leave the question open for the rest of today, if nobody comes back with something better I'll mark your answer as correct.